# How do I set an object to move along an axis by changing the rotation of a different object?

Tags: rigging, constraints

So I'm trying to model an aperture like shape, and am setting up constraints to go along with it. After a long bit of trial and error, I found out I could use the copy rotation constraint all set to one object to get the desired effect. Now I need to move the objects outward while rotating them at the same time, so I was wondering if it were possible to have the rotation also make the objects move. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: hello, some screenshots would help to understand  ;)

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/pbOYgCq)
So as you can see, the rotation works well, except now the triangles are clipping into each other. This can be fixed by moving them outwards the same time rotation is happening, which is why it would be useful if I could somehow connect the two.

Comment: ‘Drivers’ can do precisely that - ie, drive a property directly from another property (which can be from a different object). In your case though, could you get the same effect by simply moving your object’s origins to near the outer corner? This way they would pivot on the corner and move out of the doorway and you could stick with the simple Copy Rotation.

Comment: you can also use Action constraint: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm8JHVpa9Sk